# How to add multiple items to a function

Tags: javascript, function, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a shopping list function that everytime I put an item in the function parenthesis, it would automatically be added to the shopping list array. If the number of items in the array are less than or equal to 5 items, it would be good. Else it would print "The shopping list is full, can not add any other items" once the number of items exceeds 5.

In this case, I try to call the function and add multiple items at once but it doesn't work. How can I fix the problem? Your help would mean the world to me! Thank you guys.

Here is my code:

```
var x;
function shoppingListofTheWeek(x){
    var list = [["carrots", 3], ["almond milk", 1], ["cauliflower", 10], ["tea", 15]]
    
    if (list.length <= 5) {
        list.push(x);
        console.log(list);
    } else {
        console.log("The shopping list is full, can not add any other items in the cart.");
    }
}

shoppingListofTheWeek(["salmond", 2],["strawberry",15]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can use ellipsis to take multiple arguments, then loop over them.

```js
var x;

function shoppingListofTheWeek(...items) {
  var list = [
    ["carrots", 3],
    ["almond milk", 1],
    ["cauliflower", 10],
    ["tea", 15]
  ]
  items.forEach(x => {
    if (list.length <= 5) {
      list.push(x);
      console.log(list);
    } else {
      console.log("The shopping list is full, can not add any other items in the cart.");
    }
  });
}

shoppingListofTheWeek(["salmond", 2], ["strawberry", 15]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just get started to code on my own so I don’t have much knowledge. I’m still not clear on why you have a loop in the function. Could you please talk more about it?

Comment: The loop is to add each item to the shopping list, checking whether the list has reached capacity each time.

Comment: But since the shopping list always starts with 4 items in it, you'll never be able to add more than 1 item to it.